# explode grabbing page php curl to get row value

Tags: php, html, curl, explode

I already grab a page from webpage and save it in my variable `$result`. Now I want to explode it because I just want to get 1 row from all page which contain the information that I need. Here is an example of the HTML code that I grab.

```
<pre>
.....
<tr class="altRowItem">

    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="center"></td>
    <td class="fareCol1"></td>
    <td class="fareCol2">
        <p>
            <input id="ControlGroupScheduleSelectView_AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView_RadioButtonMkt1Fare4" type="radio" value="0~A~~A~RGFR~~1~X|QG~9743~ ~~CGK~04/18/2014 13:10~DPS~04/18/2014 15:55~" name="ControlGroupScheduleSelectView$AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1"></input>

            Rp.1,137,000
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
.....
</pre>
```

I just need string from `<p>` until `</p>`. Here is the code that I used.

```
$arrayResult[] = explode("<td class='fareCol2'>", $result);
echo $arrayResult[1];
```

There's nothing in `$arrayResult[1]`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for [ ], also match the quotation formatting

```
$arrayResult = explode( '<td class="fareCol2">', $result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. it's work good. I'm still new in php. i didn't know that $arrayResult already been array before.